# How find all pairs equal to N in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a problem with this algorithm- I have to find pairs in list:

```
[4, 8, 9, 0, 12, 1, 4, 2, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 11, 12, 0]
```

which are equal to `12`. The thing is that after making a pair those numbers (elements) can not be used again.

For now, I have code which you can find below. I have tried to delete numbers from the list after matching, but I feel that there is an issue with indexing after this.

It looks very easy but still not working. `;/`

```
class Pairs():

    def __init__(self, sum, n, arr ):

        self.sum = sum
        self.n = n
        self.arr = arr

    def find_pairs(self):

        self.n = len(self.arr)

        for i in range(0, self.n):
            for j in range(i+1, self.n):
                if (self.arr[i] + self.arr[j] == self.sum):
                    print("[", self.arr[i], ",", " ", self.arr[j], "]", sep = "")
                    self.arr.pop(i)
                    self.arr.pop(j-1)
                    self.n = len(self.arr)
                    i+=1


def Main():
    sum = 12
    arr = [4, 8, 9, 0, 12, 1, 4, 2, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 11, 12, 0]
    n = len(arr)
    obj_Pairs = Pairs(sum, n, arr)
    obj_Pairs.find_pairs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

update:

Thank you guys for the fast answers!

I've tried your solutions, and unfortunately, it is still not exactly what I'm looking for. I know that the expected output should look like this: [4, 8], [0, 12], [1, 11], [4, 8], [12, 0]. So in your first solution, there is still an issue with duplicated elements, and in the second one [4, 8] and [12, 0] are missing. Sorry for not giving output at the beginning.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: A simpler approach is to sort the array, and burn the candle from both ends.

Comment: Expected output should looks like : 
[4, 8], [0, 12], [1, 11], [4, 8], [12, 0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brief**

If you have learned about hashmaps and linked lists/deques, you can consider using auxiliary space to map values to their indices.

Pro:

- It does make the time complexity linear.
- Doesn't modify the input

Cons:

- Uses extra space
- Uses a different strategy from the original. If this is for a class and you haven't learned about the data structures applied then don't use this.

**Code**

```
from collections import deque # two-ended linked list

class Pairs():

    def __init__(self, sum, n, arr ):

        self.sum = sum
        self.n = n
        self.arr = arr

    def find_pairs(self):
        mp = {}  # take advantage of a map of values to their indices
        res = [] # resultant pair list
        for idx, elm in enumerate(self.arr):
            if mp.get(elm, None) is None:
                mp[elm] = deque() # index list is actually a two-ended linked list

            mp[elm].append(idx) # insert this element
            comp_elm = self.sum - elm # value that matches
            if mp.get(comp_elm, None) is not None and mp[comp_elm]: # there is no match
                # match left->right
                res.append((comp_elm, elm))
                mp[comp_elm].popleft()
                mp[elm].pop()

        for pair in res: # Display
            print("[", pair[0], ",", " ", pair[1], "]", sep = "")

        # in case you want to do further processing
        return res

def Main():
    sum = 12
    arr = [4, 8, 9, 0, 12, 1, 4, 2, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 11, 12, 0]
    n = len(arr)
    obj_Pairs = Pairs(sum, n, arr)
    obj_Pairs.find_pairs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

**Output**

```
$ python source.py
[4, 8]
[0, 12]
[4, 8]
[1, 11]
[12, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Output looks like as I wanted! I will compare this solution to another one and chose the favorite one!
thank you one more time

Answer (score 1):

With this problem you need to keep track of what numbers have already been tried. Python has a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class that will hold the count of each of the elements present in a given list.

The algorithm I would use is:

- create counter of elements in list
- iterate list

  - for each element, check if (target - element) exists in counter and count of that item > 0

    - decrement count of element and (target - element)

---

```
from collections import Counter

class Pairs():
    def __init__(self, target, arr):
        self.target = target
        self.arr = arr

    def find_pairs(self):
        count_dict = Counter(self.arr)
        result = []
        for num in self.arr:
            if count_dict[num] > 0:
                difference = self.target - num
                if difference in count_dict and count_dict[difference] > 0:
                    result.append([num, difference])
                    count_dict[num] -= 1
                    count_dict[difference] -= 1
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [4, 8, 9, 0, 12, 1, 4, 2, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 11, 12, 0]
    obj_Pairs = Pairs(12, arr)
    result = obj_Pairs.find_pairs()
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[4, 8], [8, 4], [0, 12], [12, 0], [1, 11]]
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/qGmtCkGyC)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code - few remarks:

1. If you iterate over array in `for` loop you shouldn't be changing it - use `while` loop if you want to modify the underlying list (you can rewrite this solution to use `while` loop)
2. Because you're iterating only once the elements in the outer loop - you only need to ensure you "popped" elements in the inner loop.

So the code:

```py
class Pairs():

    def __init__(self, sum, arr ):
        self.sum = sum
        self.arr = arr
        self.n = len(arr)
    
    def find_pairs(self):
        j_pop = []
        for i in range(0, self.n):
            for j in range(i+1, self.n):
                if (self.arr[i] + self.arr[j] == self.sum) and (j not in j_pop):
                    print("[", self.arr[i], ",", " ", self.arr[j], "]", sep = "")
                    j_pop.append(j)
                                    
def Main():
    sum = 12
    arr = [4, 8, 9, 0, 12, 1, 4, 2, 12, 12, 4, 4, 8, 11, 12, 0]
    obj_Pairs = Pairs(sum, arr)
    obj_Pairs.find_pairs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```